# What does HTTP 404 mean?

Tags: .net, asp.net

What does this error mean?

> HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Comment: I posted an answer here that might help.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3547217/am-running-the-web-allication-using-asp-net-am-getting-this-error/14866462#14866462

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From [the HTTP spec](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html):

> **10.4.5 404 Not Found**
>
> The server has not found anything
>   matching the Request-URI. No
>   indication is given of whether the
>   condition is temporary or permanent.
>   ... This status code is commonly
>   used when the server does not wish to
>   reveal exactly why the request has
>   been refused, or when no other
>   response is applicable.

... so it's likely that the server doesn't have (or can't find) the file you're asking it for.

If you think that the file should be there (i.e. you control the server, and you created the file):

- You're specifying the path (in the URL) incorrectly
- Your URL remapping code may not be working correctly
- There may be some configuration option that is preventing the server from finding the file.