# Am running the web allication using asp.net.am getting this error

Tags: asp.net

HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Requested URL: /webctrl_client/1_0/treeimages/Rminus.gif

Comment: do you have this image at this path?

Comment: Yeah, sounds like a path issue.  Try to load up the image in your browser using the same path.

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem for a simple reason.  Make sure you compile your site before deploying it. I had some pages that were compiled and some pages that were not compiled.  And because I was testing on a Windows Server 2008 box, not a Windows 7 box.

It took me so long to figure out because when I tried viewing these pages on the application server (Windows Server 2008), it wouldn't let me view a non secure page (http protocol), because of Internet Explorer's security settings. I only had a binding for port 80 when testing on a browser on the server box. So I couldn't even see the aspx page that was compiled, let alone the aspx pages that were not compiled. A plain HTML page was visible on both boxes however, on the same site--that part was interesting.  So that told me IIS was running fine.  When I viewed the pages on another machine (running Windows 7) on that network, the compiled aspx page showed up fine because it was compiled. And the non-compiled pages did not.

**Here are other possible issues:**

(use correct version of .NET framework for commands below)

1.) Have you installed the .NET framework?

2.) Make sure ASP.NET 4.0 is registered.  Run these commands to verify.

```
"%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe" -lv
"%systemroot%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe" list apppool /managedRuntimeVersion:v4.0
"%systemroot%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe" list config -section:system.webServer/isapiFilters
```

If not, run this:

```
"%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis" -i -enable
```

3.) Make sure the ISAPI filters are turned on for the version you are using.  Click server (not the site) in IIS 7.  Then go to "Isapi Filters".  Allow the ones you need.

4.) Make sure your application pool is running in the version of your compiled source code of your ASP.NET pages.  Go to Application Pools in IIS, then right click the application pool for your site, and choose Advanced.  Change the version to either 2.0 or 4.0.  Make sure it's also 32 bit if you compiled your app as 32 bit.

... when reading forums those are the 4 solutions I came across most frequently.  Mine was a bit simple, but confused me for hours because I hadn't installed the SSL certificate yet.