# Hello. Ihave war packaging spring boot soap webservice, i deploy to tomcat but soapui request return error

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat, soapui

I have one spring boot jar packaging helloworld soap web service and it works as jar project. But I need war file, i convert it to war packaging project and then deploy to tomcat, but when i test with soapui request return error. This is my test project link: 
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ChKcOxeOGkFpGpjYUh3FabdUFFueRWCw

**I want ask, if someone have spring boot soap web service that works correctly?**

i use eclipse maven project, tomcat 8.5.23 and soapui, jdk 1.8

this is some part of error text 
: 
HTTP Status 404 – Not Found HTTP Status 404 – Not Found /codenotfound/ws/helloworld

**Description** The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

#### Apache Tomcat/8.5.23

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does HTTP 404 mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/761695/what-does-http-404-mean)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [spring boot soap web service - 404 error when trying to access war](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47433843/spring-boot-soap-web-service-404-error-when-trying-to-access-war)

Answer (score 0):

Add "SpringBootServletInitializer" as shown in following code to your main file. Because without SpringBootServletInitializer Tomcat will consider it as normal application it will not consider as Spring boot application

```
@SpringBootApplication

public class DemoApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer{

@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
    return application.sources(DemoApplication .class);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication .class, args);
}

}
```